# ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds

Tags: lstm

I've ran into a problem and i cannot solve it there seem to be multiple errors in runfile and execfile. Any help appreciated

```
File "/home/luka/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1662, in _create_c_op
raise ValueError(str(e))

ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for 'lstm_1/strided_slice_13' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [0,?,1], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.
```

[image]